# woocommerce archive page overwrites individual store homepage

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I made an custom shop start page. But when I **set** this in the **woocommerce settings to the new shop page**, the default one overwrites it. Did someone know how to fix that? Is there some default code that makes that archive page?

I think it also has something to do with the permalinks, because if it doesn’t run under “/shop” everything is displayed correctly.

This is the body class at the wrong shop page:

```
<body class="archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-product....>
```

Thank you a lot!

[This is the correct one](https://www.log-line.de/shop-2/)

[This is the wrong one](https://www.log-line.de/shop/)

[Screenshot of the correct shop page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56iBY.jpg)

[Screenshot of the wrong shop page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pdlH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**WooCommerce** > **Settings** > **Products** > **Display** > Then change the shop page to what you want:

Maybe you can try shortcode
Like something like that:
[products limit="4" columns="2" visibility="featured" ]
You can change it to whatever you want:

[https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/](http://Maybe%20you%20can%20try%20shortcode%20https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/)